# How to enumerate Windows Drivers on Windows RT?

Tags: windows, usb, driver, remote-debugging, windows-rt

This is related to [Need USB-Ethernet NIC for Windows RT Remote Debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17387573/need-usb-ethernet-nic-for-windows-rt-remote-debugging). According to the folks at XDA, [Windows RT USB drivers may never arrive](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1966532).

How can I enumerate the existing USB and Network drivers on this Windows RT device? I might be able to find a device based on an existing driver. Remember, there are basically no programs for the tablet and RT does not allow development of desktop apps (so I can't copy/paste some sample enumeration code).